# amCharts group by Date

Tags: javascript, jquery, amcharts

I use amCharts but I need to group data results by Date:
[Demo example](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/date-based-data/?theme=none)

I have 5 visits by one day and chart need to group results.

My code:

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
    "type": "serial",
    "theme": "light",
    "marginRight": 40,
    "marginLeft": 40,
    "autoMarginOffset": 20,
    "mouseWheelZoomEnabled":true,
    "dataDateFormat": "YYYY-MM-DD",
    "valueAxes": [{
        "id": "v1",
        "axisAlpha": 0,
        "position": "left",
        "ignoreAxisWidth":true
    }],
    "balloon": {
        "borderThickness": 1,
        "shadowAlpha": 0
    },
    "graphs": [{
        "id": "g1",
        "balloon":{
            "drop":true,
            "adjustBorderColor":false,
            "color":"#ffffff"
        },
        "bullet": "round",
        "bulletBorderAlpha": 1,
        "bulletColor": "#FFFFFF",
        "bulletSize": 5,
        "hideBulletsCount": 50,
        "lineThickness": 2,
        "title": "red line",
        "useLineColorForBulletBorder": true,
        "valueField": "value",
        "balloonText": "<span style='font-size:18px;'>[[value]]</span>"
    }],
    "chartScrollbar": {
        "graph": "g1",
        "oppositeAxis":false,
        "offset":30,
        "scrollbarHeight": 80,
        "backgroundAlpha": 0,
        "selectedBackgroundAlpha": 0.1,
        "selectedBackgroundColor": "#888888",
        "graphFillAlpha": 0,
        "graphLineAlpha": 0.5,
        "selectedGraphFillAlpha": 0,
        "selectedGraphLineAlpha": 1,
        "autoGridCount":true,
        "color":"#AAAAAA"
    },
    "categoryAxesSettings": {
        "maxSeries": 1,
        "groupToPeriods": ["DD"]
    },

    "chartCursor": {
        "pan": true,
        "valueLineEnabled": true,
        "valueLineBalloonEnabled": true,
        "cursorAlpha":1,
        "cursorColor":"#258cbb",
        "limitToGraph":"g1",
        "valueLineAlpha":0.2,
        "valueZoomable":true
    },
    "valueScrollbar":{
        "oppositeAxis":false,
        "offset":50,
        "scrollbarHeight":10
    },
    "categoryField": "date",
    "categoryAxis": {
        "parseDates": true,
        "dashLength": 1,
        "minorGridEnabled": true
    },
    "export": {
        "enabled": true
    },
    "dataProvider": [
                                        {

                "date": "2016-12-01",
                "value": 1
            },
                            {

                "date": "2016-12-01",
                "value": 1
            },
                            {

                "date": "2016-12-01",
                "value": 1
            },
                            {

                "date": "2016-12-01",
                "value": 1
            },
                            {

                "date": "2016-12-01",
                "value": 1
            },



    ]
});

chart.addListener("rendered", zoomChart);

zoomChart();


function zoomChart() {
    chart.zoomToIndexes(chart.dataProvider.length - 40, chart.dataProvider.length - 1);
}
```

By documentation I use grouping settings without success.

```
"categoryAxesSettings": {
        "maxSeries": 1,
        "groupToPeriods": ["DD"]
    },
```

Any Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, `categoryAxesSettings` only applies to **stock** type charts. You're using a **serial** here. An alternative option is to translate the data yourself:

```js
function translateData(data){
  var newData = [], dates = [];
  data.map(function(item){
    var index = dates.indexOf(item.date);
    if(index > -1){
      newData[index].value += item.value;
    }else{
      newData.push(item);
      dates.push(item.date);
    }
  });
  return newData;
}
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
    "type": "serial",
    "theme": "light",
    "marginRight": 40,
    "marginLeft": 40,
    "autoMarginOffset": 20,
    "mouseWheelZoomEnabled":true,
    "dataDateFormat": "YYYY-MM-DD",
    "valueAxes": [{
        "id": "v1",
        "axisAlpha": 0,
        "position": "left",
        "ignoreAxisWidth":true
    }],
    "balloon": {
        "borderThickness": 1,
        "shadowAlpha": 0
    },
    "graphs": [{
        "id": "g1",
        "balloon":{
            "drop":true,
            "adjustBorderColor":false,
            "color":"#ffffff"
        },
        "bullet": "round",
        "bulletBorderAlpha": 1,
        "bulletColor": "#FFFFFF",
        "bulletSize": 5,
        "hideBulletsCount": 50,
        "lineThickness": 2,
        "title": "red line",
        "useLineColorForBulletBorder": true,
        "valueField": "value",
        "balloonText": "<span style='font-size:18px;'>[[value]]</span>"
    }],
    "chartScrollbar": {
        "graph": "g1",
        "oppositeAxis":false,
        "offset":30,
        "scrollbarHeight": 80,
        "backgroundAlpha": 0,
        "selectedBackgroundAlpha": 0.1,
        "selectedBackgroundColor": "#888888",
        "graphFillAlpha": 0,
        "graphLineAlpha": 0.5,
        "selectedGraphFillAlpha": 0,
        "selectedGraphLineAlpha": 1,
        "autoGridCount":true,
        "color":"#AAAAAA"
    },
    "categoryAxesSettings": {
        "maxSeries": 1,
        "groupToPeriods": ["DD"]
    },

    "chartCursor": {
        "pan": true,
        "valueLineEnabled": true,
        "valueLineBalloonEnabled": true,
        "cursorAlpha":1,
        "cursorColor":"#258cbb",
        "limitToGraph":"g1",
        "valueLineAlpha":0.2,
        "valueZoomable":true
    },
    "valueScrollbar":{
        "oppositeAxis":false,
        "offset":50,
        "scrollbarHeight":10
    },
    "categoryField": "date",
    "categoryAxis": {
        "parseDates": true,
        "dashLength": 1,
        "minorGridEnabled": true
    },
    "export": {
        "enabled": true
    },
    "dataProvider": translateData([
            {

                "date": "2016-12-01",
                "value": 1
            },
                            {

                "date": "2016-12-01",
                "value": 1
            },
                            {

                "date": "2016-12-01",
                "value": 1
            },
                            {

                "date": "2016-12-01",
                "value": 1
            },
                            {

                "date": "2016-12-01",
                "value": 1
            }
    ])
});

chart.addListener("rendered", zoomChart);

zoomChart();

function zoomChart() {
    chart.zoomToIndexes(chart.dataProvider.length - 40, chart.dataProvider.length - 1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv" style="height: 300px;"></div>
```